What will happen if one books a hotel with a gift card?
I understand that if I book a hotel using a credit card and assume that cancellation is not allowed, I risk being charged the price of one night (say $100) if I change my mind about this trip. On the other hand, the system also allows me to book with a VISA gift card, even if the balance of the gift card is low.

Say the gift card has a balance of $5, can the hotel charge me more than $5 once I cancel the booking?
When I check in at the hotel, since the balance of the gift card is not enough to cover the expense, can I use a different card (such as a credit card) to make a payment for a booking that I made with my gift card?


FYI, Rental car companies and hotels can tell if a car is a gift card or not. . Some don't accept gift cards at all. Probably because they usually want the name on the card to match the name of the person signing the contract.

Worry not only about what the credit card network allows them to charge your card -- if you sign a contract agreeing to pay for one night in case of late cancellation, they can chase you for that.

The hotels and rental car companies usually put an authorization hold for an amount enough to cover what they think would be the expected expense. Some do it at the reservation time, some do it when the cancellation period expires, some do it at check-in.
If your gift card doesn't have that amount, the hold will fail. In such case, some might just cancel the reservation, others will contact you for an alternative method of payment, or others still will just wait for you to arrive at check-in and ask for a different card. You'll probably want to reach out to the specific hotel you're interested in and ask what their policy on the matter is.

Thanks! I guess in any case, they cannot technically charge more than the balance of the gift card, right? Will they send me a bill if I cancel the trip when a cancellation is not allowed?

@Zuriel I don't know. They can put a hold on whatever value you do have, and then you'll spend weeks trying to remove it after the reservation is cancelled so that you could use the card somewhere else. Just saying...

Thank you! If my gift card only has $5, I probably wouldn't worry about it until they send me a real bill.

If your gift card only has $5, the hold will fail and the hotel won't accept, or won't honor, the reservation until you give them a card which can cover the bill.  They want to be sure they will get paid for the first night; a $5 card simply doesn't provide that guarantee and you will need to find some other way to do so. You can't cheat here; if you don't meet their (reasonable and nondiscriminatory) requirements you simply can't get the room.

For gift cards, they usually put a hold on the full amount. So there's a big chance that your reservation won't go through.
You can try hotel booking websites. Some of them have GDS properties that would only charge $5 for booking. See if the hotel that you chose is part of that.

GDS? Nothing from a quick websearch seems to apply.
